# Booting and installation problem. Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu. But. I couldn't boot back into windows (not shown at the grub) until I put this into the terminal:

sudo apt-get install lilo

sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr

It was a success. I rebooted it and it went right into my windows. But now I can’t boot back into Ubuntu. Then I tried to reinstall and repair the ubuntu. But this showed up. How can I fix this so I can dual boot and switch easily between my windows and ubuntu?  [image]

Comment: Any option I picked didn't work. I had to restart the laptop.

Comment: how did you replace grub2 with lilo?. I mean you didn't just install lilo on top of grub ,right?

Comment: I don't understand, I just followed some instructions I found at some site and put these into the terminal: 


sudo apt-get install lilo

sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr

Comment: ok, so you didn't remove grub and it's configuration when installing lilo, this is usually not a very good idea, but we'll try to fix it up. What happens when you attempt to reinstall ubuntu?, fo you tell it to use your entire partition, or do you attempt a manual partitioning?